# React component library exporting common css file with rollup

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rollup

I created a React component library with the help of Rollup.

Inside component library project there is a common css file with default theme, and I would like to be distributed separately.

What would be the best way to rollup the library and have components and css separately? And how to consume it in a main project? I have spend a day looking for the info, but there is a “library hell”, and very different information.